# SshSession.exe wakes Windows 10 from sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep

After a recent WIndows update my computer has been waking up from sleep every few minutes. The source is always SshSession. Should I just delete the exe?

```
C:\Windows\system32>powercfg /lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Wake Timer
    Owner: [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\SshSession.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Found what I was looking for. Had to stop SSDP Discovery and SSH Server Broker/SSH Server Proxy in Services

The steps are:
windows key + r, type services.msc and enter
Scroll down to SSDP Discovery, right click it, stop
Repeat for other SSH services.